# Airflow scheduler not working after manual trigger of a dag

Tags: python, cron, airflow

I have a airflow job with a daily schedule. It was running completely fine everyday, until yesterday where I manually triggered the dag a few hours after the scheduled run. The day after that (today) the task did not get executed).

```
start date - 31.08.2020 03:00 @daily -> scheduled, all good
01.09.2020 03:00 -> scheduled, all good
01.09.2020 06:00 -> manual trigger
02.09.2020 03:00 -> task was not executed!
```

I have not changed anything in the code/configuration so I suspect the manual trigger yesterday caused the dag to not run as scheduled today. Could there be another reason?

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'raydex',
    'depends_on_past': False, 
    'start_date': datetime(2020,5,31), 
}

with DAG('task', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 3 * * *', catchup=False) as dag:
```

Does anyone know what exactly has caused this? How can I prevent this issue from happening once again? I needed to manually trigger it now once again, due to the job not being scheduled. I want it to be automatically scheduled once again, starting from tommorow (03:00).

The Status is and was 'ON' in the UI.

Comment: Have the same issue, setting catchup=True is my current work around, hope some one could explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are on version 2? It seems this is a potential bug or at least unrecorded behavior change for version 2. You can find out more here.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13434